# Overriding Clone without calling the super.clone

Tags: java, clone

Is it a good practice to override `clone` method, without implementing Cloneable interface and not calling super.clone(). This way, `CloneNotSupportedException` exception will not be thrown.

Consider this class :

```
class Money {

    private BigDecimal x ;

    public Object clone() {
        Money m1 = new Money();
        m1.setX(this.x);
        return m1;
    }

    public BigDecimal getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(BigDecimal x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

This class, does not throw `CloneNotSupportedException` and it works just like a copy constructor.

Is this a good way to do it ?

Comment: It's a good practice to ignore that `clone` exists and to write your own `copy` method instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have your cloning logic and of course you know, that your class supports cloning and therefore `clone` method should not throw `CloneNotSupportedException`. So calling `super.clone()` here causes you to write boilerplate `try`/`catch` block with rethrowing `CloneNotSupportedException` wrapped inside `AssertionError`, which is obviously never thrown. And this marker `Cloneable`... I think, that this part of Java is misdesigned. So I just ignore documentation and copy fields by hands.

The only two arguments for using `super.clone()` are performance (I suppose, something like `memcpy` used internally) and persistence to errors when new fields added.

Answer (score 4):

It's bad practice not to call `super.clone()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579913/cloning-object-in-java/7580966#7580966) for more on how to implement the clone method.

Comment: By the way: note that BigDecimal objects are immutable, so in your example a shallow copy suffices.

Comment: Agreed with "bad practice", but I would like to point out the real problems with this: like subclassing, or adding a field.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's workable, but in some cases, it doesn't even work. **Implementing a `clone` method without calling `super.clone` would make it impossible to make the subclass cloneable**. For example, suppose I have a `Fruit` class

```java
public class Fruit implements Cloneable {

    private String fruitName;

    public Fruit(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }

    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }

    public Fruit clone() {
        return new Fruit(fruitName);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I implement `Fruit#clone` method without calling `super.clone`, this seems fine. But now I want to create a class `Apple` which extends `Fruit`, like this:

```java
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    private String origin;

    public Apple(String fruitName, String origin) {
        super(fruitName);
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public Apple clone() {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, how to implement Apple's `clone` method. Should I call `super.clone` inside Apple's `clone` method? Yes, you should, otherwise you cannot get the value of `fruitName`, which is a private field inside `Fruit`. OK, let's try this:

```
public Apple clone() {
    return (Apple) super.clone();
}
```

However, it didn't work. Because `Fruit#clone` doesn't call `super.clone`, so the result of `super.clone()` inside `Apple#clone` returns an instance of `Fruit` instead of `Apple`. `Fruit` cannot be cast into `Apple`, thus an error would be thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Fruit cannot be cast to Apple
    at Apple.clone(Apple.java:20)
```

So as you can see, you cannot provide a workable `clone` method for `Apple`, whether you call `super.clone` or not, it wouldn't work anyway. It's just because you didn't call `super.clone` in `Fruit#clone`.

In conclusion, you need to call `super.clone` in the `clone` method if you want the subclass to be cloneable.

Comment: Is it the only case ?
Mark the Fruit class as final will prevent this issue

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a class which has the `clone` method without telling the outside world that it is actually `Cloneable`. This is not called cloning but prototyping.

If you want to `clone` use the interface if not choose some other method name.

Please check the documentation as well:

> Creates and returns a copy of this object. The precise meaning of
>   "copy" may depend on the class of the object. The general intent is
>   that, for any object x, the expression:  x.clone() != x will be true,
>   and that the expression:  x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass() will be
>   true, but these are not absolute requirements. While it is typically
>   the case that:  x.clone().equals(x) will be true, this is not an
>   absolute requirement. By convention, the returned object should be
>   obtained by calling super.clone. If a class and all of its
>   superclasses (except Object) obey this convention, it will be the case
>   that x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass().

There is a reason you have to call `super.clone()`.

Comment: Your quote confirms that OP's implementation does not break the contract.

Comment: **By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone**

Comment: What happens if someone wants to actually override `clone`?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the term *should*? Hint: it is different from *must*.

Comment: I think most java conventions are "must". If you don't follow them others get confused. At least he shouldn't name it `clone` but `copy` like others commented.

Comment: My point was, OP is not breaking the contract. He is straying from convention, but that's a separate point. If his class is `final`, for example, it cannot even be determined from the outside whether or not he is relying on `super.clone()`. Nobody gets confused by invisible implementation details.

Comment: I see. What is your suggestion? How he should solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem in the question. He is asking whether "it is a good way to do it". So my answer would be "if you plan to make your class `final`, then it's perfectly OK."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42315/discussion-between-adam-arold-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 0):

clone is all about the coping/duplicating the type and state of an object. And if we have to identify the type and it make sense to have it associated with the Object class. Java by nature, operates by reference and by principle of shallow copy. If we have to enable deep copy then user has to indicate the runtime special handling is been done in clone(). And that is done by tagging with the Clonable interface.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically adding an override of clone is the right way to enforce the prototype pattern, i.e. creating copies of an object at runtime without knowing the type.

Practically its a different story. Clone is the API standard way to do it. When you are writing your own clone method for a standalone class its ok to drop the super.clone call and go ahead. But its a naive practice. Assume that you have a class which follows an inheritance mechanism. Imagine, a Lion which is a Carnivore and thus in turn is an Animal. Now if you drop the super.clone in Lion you could end up recreating a copy of Lion without it being a Carnivore or god forbid even an Animal.

So its best to follow the API standards and keep yourself free of any hickups.