# Code snippet with inconsistent output

Tags: java, deep-copy

I am trying the following code where I want to make a deep copy of main object and make changes in the new created object `person1`. But the change get reflected in both the object. So as result main object should remain same and new created object's `state` should be `null`. And also `synchronized` blocks are used.

```
class Person {    
    public void persist() {
        print(this.toString()); //print whole object 
        Person person1 = new Person ();
        person1.setName(this.getName());
        person1.setAddress(this.getAddress());
        for(Address address : person1.getAddress()) {
            address.setState(null);
        }
        print(person1.toString()); //printobject with state as null
        print(this.toString());  // print object with state as null(ERROR)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete `Person` / `Address` class, see [mcve] (smells like `static`)

Comment: You're not making a deep copy - a deep copy goes all the way, not just one level. You also need to deep-copy `address`

Answer (score 0):

What you are providing in person1.setAddress(this.getAddress()); is the address of current address in new object you need to copy the data if you want a deep copy

eg

```
Person p1=new Person();
List<Address> addList;
for(Address add:this.getAddress())
{
addList.add(new Address(add.getstreet,add.getHome,null/*this is state*/));
}

p1.setAddress(addList);
```

After you have copied only your data not object reference u can try to change the address the main object will not change or you can use Clone Method

eg: [How to make a deep copy of Java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042182/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-java-arraylist)

Comment: Thnx ..You saved my life.Yes the issue was that i was doing deep copy at one level.I used your way and it worked fine.Thnx a lot..

Answer (score 0):

As you've not posted your complete code, i assume signature of methods as `void Person.setName(Address add)` and `Address Person.getName()`

what i suspect is when you are calling setName method by passing reference of Address of `this` Person, your setName method's implementation is just copying reference of passed Address to Person1's Address.
 In case of deep copy you should not copy reference as now both `this` Person and Person1 points to same Address and any changes made to Address will now reflect in both the Person object.
 You can avoid this by first [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579913/cloning-object-in-java) Address object(say adrs_new) in the implementation of `setName` and assign this adrs_new to Person1's Address instead of passed Address.

Comment: Thnx.. Yes deep copy required at all the levels.Now worked.