# Overriding Clone() method in Java when superclass is not Clonable

Tags: java, cloning

[How to clone a Java object with the clone() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579913/how-to-clone-a-java-object-with-the-clone-method/7580966#7580966)

I have a question regarding properly implementing the `clone()` method for a class in java.
I know that this is bad practice, but I need to know this for an exam..
In the above discussion they say to call `super.clone()` - but I don't udnerstand what happens if the super function doesn't implement Clonable.
For example, say I have a class X that extends Y. X implements Clonable and Y doesnl't. Y's `clone()` method should throw an Exception. Then what do we do in this case?

All the explanations I could find somehow assume that all superclasses implement Clonable, or at least that's what I understood..

EDIT:

Check out this code please:

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable {

private String name;

public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
    return (Employee)super.clone();  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp = new Employee("Abhi");
    try {
        Employee emp2 = (Employee) emp.clone();
        System.out.println(emp2.getName());
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It is taken from here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/03/understanding-cloneable-interface-in-java.html

Similar code can be found in many tutorials.

Why can they use `super.clone()` when the superclass (which in this case is `Object`) does not implement Clonable - that would result in an Exception.

Comment: If 'superclass is not Clonable' means superclass does not implement 'Clonable' interface - there will be no super.clone() method, so you would not be able to call it. So what the question?

Comment: So how do I clone in this case? How do I override the clone() method?

Comment: Object does not implement Clonable as well.. So every class extends Object.. So we will always reach a not Clonable class using super.clone()... So why do we do that in every clone() implementation I could find?

Comment: @AlexChernyshev There _will_ be a `super.clone()`, because it's declared on `Object`; it just won't work if the object does implement `Clonable`

Comment: You cannot override something that does not exist, so  full clone() method implementation will be yours. In simplest case  just return new instance of class with copied fields.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev [`clone()` is a method of `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).  Thus, every object in Java does have a `clone()`-method (with more than questionable behaviour).

Comment: I added a code example when this thing happens.

Comment: @Andy That is not correct. `Object.clone()` will clone all the private fields  and not throw `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: @Andy this is exactly my question - this should throw a runtime exception. So why is this used?

Comment: @Andy The derived class implements `Cloneable`, which turns that behaviour off. Try it before you post any more misinformation.

Comment: @Turing85 ok thanks for noticing that, hope you also seen that  'Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the Cloneable interface results in the exception CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.'  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html So is it much differs from not having such method at all ?

Comment: @AlexChernyshev and I hope you know that [`Cloneable` is broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch.html).

Comment: @AlexChernyshev The OP's instance *does* implement `Cloneable`. You guys need to read more carefully.

Comment: @Turing85 lot of people think that 'Java is broken' , so?  Let's stay on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this structure:

```
class Y {}

class X extends Y implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    public X clone() {
        try {
            return (X) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e);
        } 
    }
}
```

Then clone on instances of `X` will work fine.
It won't work on direct instances of `Y`, because they are not declared cloneable. But the `Cloneable` interface on `X` is an indicator to the mechanisms of the default `clone()` implementation that they should be made to work.

**Alternatively**

You could also have a non-Cloneable class with a working `clone()` method, as long as you didn't rely on the default implementation of `clone()`.

For instance:

```
class Y {
    @Override
    public Y clone() {
        // Don't call super.clone() because it will error
        return new Y(...); // whatever parameters
    }
}
```

However, with *this* mechanism, if you called `super.clone()` from a subclass of `Y`, you would get an instance of `Y`, which is probably not what you would want.

As others have pointed out, the `Cloneable` mechanism is awkward and confusing, and usually copying mechanisms using `new` are easier to work with.

Comment: Why does it work on instances of X? The clone method you've written would result in an Exception. And what do you mean by the default implementation?

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess Would result in an exception why? Have you tried it? Have you read the Javadoc for `Object.clone()` which is the default implementation? Too much guesswork in this question.

Comment: The clone methods in my answer would work without an error. The default implementation of `clone()` is the one that you get from calling `super.clone()` all the way up to the `Object` class, and that works as long as the instance you're cloning implements `Clonable`

Comment: @khelwood I read in the Java API that when a class does not implement Clonable, its clone method results in an exception. So do you mean that there is a different implementation to that?

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess Your class *does* implement `Cloneable`. And I think you misread what you read.

Comment: @khelwood true that (deleted the comment already). This, however, will only work as long as `Y` itself does not override `clone()` with, e.g. `return new Y();`.

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess If `X` implements `Clonable`, then you can call `super.clone()` and it won't throw an exception, even if `Y` is not clonable, because **the object you're cloning** is still an instance of `X`, a clonable class.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, the `Cloneable` magic only works if you use `super.clone()` all the way up the inheritance hierarchy to `Object`.

Comment: @khelwood I'm sorry if this is common knowledge but I'm struggling to understand - the object I'm cloning is indeed an instance of X. But as far as I know, the word "super" is a reference to Y's clone() method. And if Y isn't Clonable, then how come Y's clone method doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess The instance on which you are calling `super.clone()` is `Cloneable`. That's all that matters. There is no wording to the effect you suggest. Otherwise the whole mechanism would be completely useless.

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess Because the JVM checks "is this object I'm trying to clone a member of a class that implements `Cloneable`?" If it is, then create a copy of it. If it's not, throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess 'I read in the Java API that when a class does not implement `Cloneable`, its clone method results in an exception': no you didn't. Have a good look at what it really says.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Cloneable`-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Cloneable.html) is generally [regarded as broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch.html) ([and won't be fixed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4098033)). At the core, the argument revolves around the fact that [`clone()` is a method defined on `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()), instead of being a method of the interface [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

I would not recommend using it at all. A better solution would be to provide [copy-constructors](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor). If one does not have the capability to fully recreate a parent-class object, then cloning is impossible.

Refactoring the code provided would lead to a result similar to this:

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable {

    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee(Employee that) {
        this.name = that.name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee("Abhi");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(emp);
        System.out.println(emp2.getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

A remark on your code:

```
public class Employee {
    public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
        return (Employee)super.clone();  
    }
}
```

The type cast is superfluous since the methode returns an `Object`.

Comment: I know about copy constructors, but I'm asking because we are required in class to know this as well

Comment: Then tell your professor/supervisor/teacher that `Cloneable` is (was and will be) broken and should not be used. If s/he asks why, point her/him to the link I have provided. For reference: Josh Bloch was a software engineer at Sun Microsystems and has implemented, among other things, the `Collections` framework.

Comment: Of course, Java being Java where objects do not need to have an explicit owner, the trick is usually not to have to clone anything at all. Preferably classes could be made immutable so that cloning is completely superfluous (you can still have methods that return a changed object instance, by the way).